# How to find an element in new Webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a form. I automated the task of filling up the form and clicking the submit button using Selenium WebDriver.

Now in the next page where the URL has changed, there is a confirmation message "Form Submitted Successfully". How do I verify this element in the new URL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need a better answer i will need more info, but you can ask your `webdriver` to find a element that you know will be in that new url or you can get the current url like `webdriver.getCurrentUrl()`, now you need to wait for the new page to be loaded.

Comment: Is the confirmation in an Alert box;, i.e. do you have to click OK?  Is the confirmation in its own iFrame? Is the confirmation part of the next web page that is displayed? As acardose said, you need to supply more information.

Comment: The confirmation part of the next web page that is displayed. It is located inside a <div> element.

I figured it how and it works fine now. I used the WebDriver() to locate this element and got its contents thru getText() method.

Thank you all for your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, even if the objects you are working on are on different page(url) it does not matter, you just need to have your locator correctly written.

Using getText() method you could get text on the page. Verify whether your locator is pointing to correct text using xpath validaters or other means.

Once you have your locator handy apply getText() method on it and get the text.

Once you have text, just verify it or print it to see if it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JUnit assertion to compare **expected** string with **actual** the one you getting on the page, this should work :

```
String actual = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_locator").getText();
Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
```